# iOS Game Center - designing game achievements for offline use

Tags: ios, game-center, offline, achievements

I am designing and developing iOS game with achievements and leaderboards. I understand the mechanic of creating achievements within iTunes Connect, and loading/unlocking them in iOS game.

But I am not aware of the best practice how to include the achievements for users that refuse using the Game Center. I want to offer these users the achievements too, so is the approach to keep a duplicate, offline list of achievements in the iOS binary and unlock these in local application?

I am not talking about "offline" in context of "network connection", but in context of "not using Game Center".

Or is this thought off-topic today, and should I hard-wire the achievements to only GC users? My intention is to offer Achievements to all users, even those who don't authorize game in GC.

Any advice in approach would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have to build your own game center like system then. There was a very popuplar game score system (Openfeint) but after game center nobody uses it anymore at least I havent seen any games use Openfeint anymore for a long time. And this is off-topic indeed.

Comment: Yeah, I know Openfeint, there were also a few others. I am ready for the option of having "GC-only" game, but I just wanted some opinion, if it does worth it - if 99 % of users is using it, then I won't offer the "non-GC" feature anyway. But this is probably for another _search-for-GC-usage-stats_ topic. Thanks anyway!